# Greadlink not working

Tags: terminal, gnu-coreutils

recently I installed CoreUtils with HomeBrew for my terminal on macOS. However, when I use the greadlink command, I am unable to get the proper file path. What I mean to say is that every time I do the following:

```
My-MBP: insertnamehere$ greadlink -f something.apk
```

I get:

```
/Users/insertnamehere/projects/something.apk
```

When its actually located at:

```
/Users/insertnamehere/Documents/stuff/something.apk
```

The same happens for any directory. Basically, it will list the file that I'm trying to find directly under that directory.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Weird right? Did you find a solution? I just started using `mdfind` to do a Spotlight search for the file then copy the path and then move the file. I'd like to use the coreutils though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grealpath` which gives more options like -P and -L etc.